# Проблема с hook в gitolite

Tags: linux, git, shell

Делаю задачу класса "велосипед" для своего проекта. Проект живет на VPS и заведен в git-репозиторий. Дописал что-то, делаешь commit+push, заходишь на сервер по SSH, тыкаешь в папке веб-сервера git pull - изменения сливаются, все довольны.

Надоело постоянно лазить на сервер ради элементарной команды. Помню, что у gitolite была система hooks, которая умела вызывать что-то при событиях репозиториев.

Отлично. Беру репозиторий, кладу в папку hooks свой скрипт с названием `post-receive`, права на выполнение

Файл проще некуда (подсмотрено в гугле, поменял пути только). Лежит в папке репозитория `/home/git/repositories/project.git/hooks` (это на самом деле папка репозиториев, сам скрипт выполняется)

```
#!/bin/bash
#CONFIG

read oldrev newrev refname
if [ $refname = "refs/heads/develop" ]; then
    echo "Updating develop..."
    cd /var/www/develop/
    umask 002
    git checkout develop
    git pull origin develop
    echo "Updated"
    cd /var/www/develop/documentation/api/
    ./raml2html.sh
    echo "Documenation regenerated"
fi
```

На клиенте все совсем не так, как я ожидал:

```
[usr@centos]$ git commit -a -m "ADD: Documentation generator" && git push origin develop
[develop abeb9bd] ADD: Documentation generator
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
Enter passphrase for key '/home/usr/.ssh/id_rsa':
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 417 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Updating develop...
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
remote: Updated
remote: Generation auth documentation section...
remote: Documenation regenerated
To git@domain.xyz:project
   13612e5..abeb9bd  develop -> develop
```

То есть git - не git, и ни checkout, ни pull не срабатывают, заявляя, что тут нет git репозитория. Хотя они там есть.

Скрипт хука отдельно, если выполнить его из под пользователя git на сервере - отрабатывает на ура, все находит, все пуллит, вообще красавчик. А из под того же git при возникновении события - никак.

Не могу понять в чем дело и что надо поправить, чтоб работало как мне надо.

Comment: а push'ишь по голому ssh от своего пользователя? если нет, то может сервер за'`chroot`'ен в свой `/home/git`...

Comment: Нет, зачем, `git push origin master`, вон же в примере видно - авторизация по SSH по ключу идет, смотри на `Enter passphrase for key '/home/usr/.ssh/id_rsa':`. Это на самом деле без разницы - вопрос больше в специфике выполнения самого хука, читаю вот документацию, пока не понятно, что мешает ему просто выполнить команду

Comment: анализируйте передаваемые скрипту переменные окружения. список: `$ man git`, секция *environment variables*.

Comment: хук с виду вроде бы в порядке... я больше подозреваю, что gitolite/ssh делает какую-то хитрую штуку связанную с безопасностью... локально с сервера не пробовал push'ить? что-то вроде `cd /tmp && git clone /home/git/repositories/project.git/ && touch test_file && git commin -m "test" test_file && git push`?.. а ещё сдампи `env` при работе скрипта — может там в среде что-то интересное устанавливается...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'`

в принципе, абсолютно логично, ведь текущий каталог (`/var/www/develop/`) явно **не** является git-хранилищем (а является лишь рабочей копией хранилища). само же хранилище у вас наверняка находится в подкаталоге `.git`.

путь к хранилищу программа *git* черпает (помимо опций) из переменной окружения `GIT_DIR` (см. `$ man git`, секция `environment variables`), которая и присутствует в окружении, передаваемом hook-у.

поэтому вам надо либо явно передавать программе путь к хранилищу, либо очистить эту переменную окружения (а на всякий случай и `GIT_WORK_TREE`):

- либо вставить перед первым вызовом *git* команду:

  ```
  unset GIT_DIR GIT_WORK_TREE
  ```
- либо вставить перед первым вызовом *git* команду:

  ```
  export GIT_DIR=/var/www/develop/.git GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/develop
  ```
- либо передавать пути опциями:

  ```
  git --git-dir=/var/www/develop/.git --work-tree=/var/www/develop ...
  ```

Comment: OP писал,что вручную хук отрабатывает нормально, так что, вероятно, `/var/www/develop/` — это всё же полноценная git-репа, созданная `git clone /home/git/repositories/project.git/` или вроде того...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, 1. цитирую: «**Скрипт** хука отдельно, если выполнить его из под пользователя git на сервере - отрабатывает на ура» (выделено мною). // 2. именно полноценная **рабочая копия** (aka «work tree»). а **хранилище** (aka «репозиторий») находится, как и обычно, в каталоге `/var/www/develop/.git`

Comment: да, согласен, очитался... сейчас проверил — правда при исполнении хука выставляется `GIT_DIR="."`... тоже подозревал что-то такое, но задвинул на второй план т.к. (по понятным причинам) с не голыми репами аналогичные скрипты работали...

Comment: Да, совершенно верно, проблема была в окружении. Я уже начал догадываться об этом, ваш ответ расставил все точки над i и разъяснил. Благодарю за уделенное время ) Теперь все работает как часы